# Facebook apprequest not linking to my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, titanium, google-play, facebook-app-requests

I am developing an Android application, to send a Facebook app request.

When I click notification in Facebook, it is redirecting to Google Play even when the app is installed. In Google Play it shows the option "OPEN", and "UNINSTALL". The expected answer should be to launch my app.

I am using Titanium Appcelerator to develop, In Google Developer I am using my account as an alpha tester.

I am sure that I have to modify my tiapp.xml file.

```
 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
        <manifest>
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"
                android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false"/>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
            <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Action">
                <activity
                    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                    android:label="my_app"
                    android:launchMode="singleTask"
                    android:name=".ApplicationActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                    <intent-filter>
                        <data android:host="" android:scheme="schemaurl"/>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    </android>
```